# Python, Pandas: How to club rows rows of dataframe based on Start Time and End Time

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe like this:

```
Start Time  End Time        IDs
15:02:13    15:10:24        BAMB30
19:46:19    19:46:29        BHI110
19:47:01    19:57:04        BHI110
19:47:01    19:56:58        BHI110
19:47:01    19:56:59        BHI110
12:01:46    12:06:30        AKB286
```

I want to **group rows** or (IDs in rows) into something called "**events**" which are defined as follows:

1. Start Time difference in an event should be <= 2 minutes.
2. End time difference in an event should be <= 2 minutes.
3. Same value in columns C1, C2 in each event.
4. Different/Unique IDs in each event.
5. An event is valid only when size of the group based on 1 and 2 is >5.

So the end result I want is like this:

```
Start Time  End Time             IDs             Event
    15:02:13    15:10:24        BAMB30      
    19:46:19    19:46:29        BHI110
    19:47:01    19:57:04        BHI110           1
    19:47:01    19:56:58        BHI110           1
    19:47:01    19:56:59        BHI110           1
    12:01:46    12:06:30        AKB286
```

We want to give numbers to the events. For example if some rows belong to an event, we will give the same number to all those rows in an event column.

So how to proceed with this?

**Edit:**

I tried the code as per your advise:

```py
def tDlt(row):
    st, et, sid, c1, c2 = row[['Start Time (HHMM)', 'End Time (HHMM)', 'IDs', 'C1', 'C2']]
    if(tDlt.start is None):
        tDlt.start, tDlt.end, tDlt.id, tDlt.c1, tDlt.c2, tDlt.ev = st, et, sid, c1, c2, 0
    else:
        if(((st - tDlt.start).total_seconds() > 120) or ((et - tDlt.end).total_seconds() > 120) or (sid == tDlt.id) or  (c1!=tDlt.c1) or (c2!=tDlt.c2)):
            tDlt.start, tDlt.end, tDlt.id, tDlt.c1, tDlt.c2 = st, et, sid, c1, c2
            tDlt.ev += 1
    return tDlt.ev

def gen_events():
    global df
    global sizeLimit
    x = list(df['Start Time (HHMM)'])
    y = list(df['End Time (HHMM)'])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = str(x[i])

    for i in range(len(y)):
        y[i] = str(y[i])

    df['Start Time (HHMM)'] = x
    df['End Time (HHMM)'] = y

    df['Start Time (HHMM)'] = df['Start Time (HHMM)'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
    df['End Time (HHMM)'] = df['End Time (HHMM)'].apply(pd.Timedelta)  
    tDlt.start = None
    ev = df.sort_values(['Start Time (HHMM)', 'End Time (HHMM)','IDs']).apply(tDlt, axis=1)
    ev = ev.groupby(ev).transform(lambda grp: str(grp.iloc[0]) if grp.size > sizeLimit else '')
    df['Event'] = ev[ev != ''].groupby(ev, sort=False).ngroup() + 1
    df.Event.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
    df = df.dropna(how='all')
    fs = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls .xlsm"),("CSV files", ".csv")])
    if((str(fs))[-3:] == "csv"):
        df.to_csv(fs)
    else:
        df.to_excel(fs)
    done()
```

Note: I require grouping events by **DIFFERENT IDS** (not same), that is why I put `(sid == tDlt.id)`in the else condition of the code.

But I am getting incorrect results in some parts using this:
[image]

As you can see, I want a single event to have different IDs but it is still grouping with some same IDs. Where in the code am I going wrong?

Note: These are not the only columns which I have in my dataframe. However, only the above mentioned columns matter while finding the events.
Thank you!

Comment: In your expected result you did't include "19:47:01 19:56:59" row in group *1*. Why? Another detail: This group has only **2** rows, but you want an event to contain at least **5** rows.

Comment: Please explain better your criteria

Comment: Your code compares each row in a group with the **previous** row only. But I think that:
1. The source group should be first sorted by both start and end times (your data sample
is **not** sorted).
2. A group should include rows with start / end time within the given limit from both times in some "initial" row (not necessarily the first).
Write also whether a single group (by *IDs*) can contain **multiple** events.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo "19:47:01 19:56:59", Yes sorry, this will also be included. Yes, it has to contain at least 5 rows to be called an event. I needed a big dataframe to illustrate this. I have edited it. Yes, single group CAN contain multiple events because each each row can overlap into >1 groups.

Comment: @gtomer We need to group the rows into events. The length of each group should be >5 and each row of the group should have start-time and end-time differing by at most 2 minutes (absolute difference).

Comment: So how should my approach be? I can first sort the dataframe based on start time as `df.sort(by="Start Time", ascending = True)`. After that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present a more instructive example, I took the following
source DataFrame:

```
   Start Time End Time     IDs  C1  C2
0    15:02:13 15:10:24  BAMB30  X9  Y9
1    19:46:19 19:46:29  BHI110  X9  Y9
2    19:47:01 19:57:04  BHI110  D2  F2
3    19:47:01 19:56:58  BHI110  D2  E2
4    19:47:01 19:56:59  BHI110  D2  E2
5    20:00:02 20:20:00  BHI110  G3  H3
6    20:01:03 20:21:16  BHI110  G3  H3
7    20:15:00 20:23:20  BHI110  X9  Y9
8    12:01:46 12:06:30  AKB286  A1  B1
9    12:02:48 12:06:50  AKB286  A1  B1
10   12:02:50 12:06:55  AKB286  A1  C1
```

I added *C1* and *C2* columns (to be compared on equality within
the current group), according to your comment.

Since both *Start Time* and *End Time* columns are of *string* type,
the first step is to convert them to *Timedelta*:

```
df['Start Time'] = df['Start Time'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
df['End Time'] = df['End Time'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
```

Then I defined a size limit for a group to be considered as an *Event*.
You wrote about this limit == *5*, but since both your and my data
sample contain only smaller groups, I set this limit at **2**:

```
sizeLimit = 2
```

Of course, running my code on your real data, change this limit to
whatever you need.

Then define a function to check the "time delta" between the current
row and the "starting row" and generate "event numbers":

```
def tDlt(row):
    st, et, c1, c2 = row[['Start Time', 'End Time', 'C1', 'C2']]
    if tDlt.start is None:
        tDlt.start, tDlt.end, tDlt.ev, tDlt.c1, tDlt.c2 = st, et, 0, c1, c2
    else:
        if ((st - tDlt.start).total_seconds() > 120)\
                or ((et - tDlt.end).total_seconds() > 120)\
                or (c1 != tDlt.c1) or (c2 != tDlt.c2):
            tDlt.start, tDlt.end, tDlt.c1, tDlt.c2 = st, et, c1, c2
            tDlt.ev += 1
    return tDlt.ev
```

Due to usage of its internal attributes, it is a "function with memory",
keeping in *start* and *end* attributes respective values from the
previous row and *ev* attribute - the event number.

This function will be applied to each row of the DataFrame, but before
it, its *start* attribute will be set to *None*, to provide proper dealing
with the first row.

Note that the starting row is set:

- on the first row (when *tDlt.start is None*),
- on each row "too distant in time" from the "starting" row or with
  *C1* or *C2* different from th e"starting" row.

This function generates consecutive "event numbers":

- starting from *0*,
- increased whenever the any condition to continue the current group
  has not been met,
- for **all** groups, even those below the size limit.

The main processing runs as follows:

1. Set the "initial value" in *start* attribute of *tDlt* function:

   ```
    tDlt.start = None
   ```
2. Sort *df* and apply *tDlt* to each row:

   ```
    ev = df.sort_values(['Start Time', 'End Time']).apply(tDlt, axis=1)
   ```

   The result (for my data sample) is:

   ```
    8     0
    9     0
    10    1
    0     2
    1     3
    3     4
    4     4
    2     5
    5     6
    6     6
    7     7
    dtype: int64
   ```

   Of course, the row order is different, due to the sort before
   the application.

   Check e.g. rows with indices *3*, *4* and *2*. Row *3* is the earliest
   from this group. Row *4* is within the same group (all conditions met).
   But row *2* has different value in *C2* column, so it starts a new
   group.
3. The next step is to cancel group numbers for "too small" groups:

   ```
    ev = ev.groupby(ev).transform(lambda grp: str(grp.iloc[0])
        if grp.size >= sizeLimit else '')
   ```

   Steps:

   - take each group (by value) and check its size,
   - if it has at least *sizeLimit* rows, return the original group
     number, but as a string (for each row),
   - otherwise return an empty string (also for each row) - the
     actual cancellation.

   The result is:

   ```
    8     0
    9     0
    10     
    0      
    1      
    3     4
    4     4
    2      
    5     6
    6     6
    7      
    dtype: object
   ```
4. Now perform "initial filling" of the new column:

   ```
    df['Event'] = ev[ev != ''].groupby(ev, sort=False).ngroup() + 1
   ```

   Steps:

   - Take non-empty elements from *ev*.
   - Group them (by their value).
   - Return the "global" group number, starting from *1*. Note that
     the "initial group numbers" (computed so far) are here changed
     into **consecutive** numbers.

   But this is not the final content yet (print *df* at this stage),
   because:

   - cells for "too short" groups contain *NaN*,
   - elements are of *float* type.
5. To get rid of the above deficiencies, run:

   ```
    df.Event.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
   ```

The final result, sorted by both times, is:

```
   Start Time End Time     IDs  C1  C2 Event
8    12:01:46 12:06:30  AKB286  A1  B1     1
9    12:02:48 12:06:50  AKB286  A1  B1     1
10   12:02:50 12:06:55  AKB286  A1  C1      
0    15:02:13 15:10:24  BAMB30  X9  Y9      
1    19:46:19 19:46:29  BHI110  X9  Y9      
3    19:47:01 19:56:58  BHI110  D2  E2     2
4    19:47:01 19:56:59  BHI110  D2  E2     2
2    19:47:01 19:57:04  BHI110  D2  F2      
5    20:00:02 20:20:00  BHI110  G3  H3     3
6    20:01:03 20:21:16  BHI110  G3  H3     3
7    20:15:00 20:23:20  BHI110  X9  Y9
```

As you can see:

- First 2 rows are close enough in time, so the are event *1*.
- The third row has *Start Time* too distant from the previous row,
  so it has not been included in the above group.
- It is also too distant from the next row, so they can not be
  grouped in an event.
- Rows *3* and *4* form the next group.
- Row *2* is excluded, due to different value in *C2*.
- And so on.

Most likely, your both columns to be checked for equality can have
other names, so put their actual names in *tDlt* instead of *C1* and *C2*.

## Edit following comment about grouping by IDs

Change the function to:

```
def tDlt(row):
    id, st, et, c1, c2 = row[['IDs', 'Start Time', 'End Time', 'C1', 'C2']]
    if tDlt.start is None:
        tDlt.id, tDlt.start, tDlt.end, tDlt.ev, tDlt.c1, tDlt.c2 = id, st, et, 0, c1, c2
    else:
        if id != tDlt.id\
                or ((st - tDlt.start).total_seconds() > 120)\
                or ((et - tDlt.end).total_seconds() > 120)\
                or (c1 != tDlt.c1) or (c2 != tDlt.c2):
            tDlt.id, tDlt.start, tDlt.end, tDlt.c1, tDlt.c2 = id, st, et, c1, c2
            tDlt.ev += 1
    return tDlt.ev
```

After `tDlt.start = None` change the next instruction to:

```
ev = df.sort_values(['IDs', 'Start Time', 'End Time']).apply(tDlt, axis=1)
```

I suppose that you added an internal attribute for *IDs*, but forgot to sort
the source DataFrame on *IDs*.

To test this code, I added 2 rows:

```
11   20:00:02   20:20:00  XXX110  G3  H3
12   20:01:03   20:21:16  XXX110  G3  H3
```

Note that they are just like rows with indices *5* and *6*, but
there is different *IDs*.

The result, for such extended data, sorted on *IDs*, *Start Time* and *End Time* is:

```
   Start Time End Time     IDs  C1  C2 Event
8    12:01:46 12:06:30  AKB286  A1  B1     1
9    12:02:48 12:06:50  AKB286  A1  B1     1
10   12:02:50 12:06:55  AKB286  A1  C1      
0    15:02:13 15:10:24  BAMB30  X9  Y9      
1    19:46:19 19:46:29  BHI110  X9  Y9      
3    19:47:01 19:56:58  BHI110  D2  E2     2
4    19:47:01 19:56:59  BHI110  D2  E2     2
2    19:47:01 19:57:04  BHI110  D2  F2      
5    20:00:02 20:20:00  BHI110  G3  H3     3
6    20:01:03 20:21:16  BHI110  G3  H3     3
7    20:15:00 20:23:20  BHI110  X9  Y9      
11   20:00:02 20:20:00  XXX110  G3  H3     4
12   20:01:03 20:21:16  XXX110  G3  H3     4
```

so rows from *XXX110* are members of a separate event.

Comment: I ran the above code. It groups the IDs with the SAME name and then checks on the start-time and end-time condition. What I want is to group the rows as a whole. An event need not have IDs of the same name. All it will have is the ROWS having same start time and same end time, +/- 2 minutes. Plus size>5. Thanks!

Comment: I reworked my answer, so that no grouping by *IDs* takes place. It is now even shorter and there is no "two-level" grouping, which was a difficult to trace operation.

Comment: Did you also consider that one row can belong to the more than one events as well? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation. Now if I want to further segregate the events based on two additional column values being exactly same (in addition to start time and end time), how can I modify this code? Thanks again

Comment: I think, it is rather material for another question. You should also describe more precisely what are these new columns and include some example of source data and expected result. It also not clear what you mean writing "segregate". Probably it should be a new column. Describe all details in a new question.

Comment: There are two additional columns with string values. I need to further shorten the event based on these two columns, this time its EXACT equality instead of deviation. So all in all, events have to be formed based on 4 columns now. First two columns are start and end time +/- 2 min, which is already done. Other two columns have string values and event is formed only on equality of those two columns for each row. If this can be solved or added here, then fine. Otherwise I would make a separate thread for it. Thanks!

Comment: For this, in your `def tDlt(row):`, I have added two more columns. It's correct only, right?

Comment: Apologies for this very late reply. I have followed your procedure for columns C1 and C2, and its working! Thanks. I require one more modification in this. I'll also want to group all the rows with UNIQUE IDS. I tried modifying your code as follows `st, et, id, c1, c2 = row[['Start Time', 'End Time', 'IDs', 'C1', 'C2']]`, but it didn't work. It still gave me an event with same IDs. Can you please help me out (if its possible to answer here)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I actually require grouping by DIFFERENT IDs including those other conditions. I have tried putting `if(sid == tDlt.id)` in the code instead and I have edited my question above. I am getting the same IDs in some parts of my output (in the same events). Can you please have a look and tell me where in the code am I going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I think, it is rather a material for another question.

Comment: Alright, I am creating another question, I'll link that here. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted as a separate question (as a follow up to this one): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062191/python-pandas-how-to-club-rows-rows-of-dataframe-based-on-start-time-end-time